# Top alignment of columns of tables with multicol package

Tags: tables, itemize, multicol, alignment

I am trying to have a "normal" text in one column of a table in Latex and a multicol environment with items in the neighbouring column. Unfortunately, the text in the left column slides down and is not top aligned. Can anyone help me? Here is a minimal example:
[image: Example]

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
paper=portrait,
onecolumn,
fontsize=12pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}[h]{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}\hline
        Test 1      &       Test\\ \hline
        Test 2      &       Test\\ \hline
        Test 3      &       
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                    \begin{multicols*}{2}
                        \begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut,leftmargin=1em]
                            \item item 1
                                \item item 2
                            \item item 3
                            \item item 4
                            \item item 5
                            \item item 6
                            \item item 7
                            \item item 8
                                \item item 9
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{multicols*}
                \end{minipage}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I always use \hsize (instead of \linewidth) inside a p column..  \hsize is what is used by \vbox, \vtop and \vcenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
paper=portrait,
onecolumn,
fontsize=12pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[h]{|p{0.47\textwidth}|p{0.47\textwidth}|}\hline
        Test 1      &       Test\\ \hline
        Test 2      &       Test\\ \hline
        Test 3      &       
        \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                    \begin{multicols*}{2}
                        \begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=1em]
                            \item item 1
                                \item item 2
                            \item item 3
                            \item item 4
                            \item item 5
                            \item item 6
                            \item item 7
                            \item item 8
                                \item item 9
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{multicols*}
                \end{minipage}
                        \end{adjustbox}\vskip0cm
                \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. However, the total width of this `tabular` environment is `1\textwidth  + 4\tabcolsep + 3\arrayrulewidth`. Better to use a `tabularx` environment, set its target width to `\textwidth`, and use two `X`-type columns.

Comment: @Mico I'm looking forward to upvote your answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz !! But how can I adjust the spacing on the bottom back to what I had ... ?

Comment: @FlorianGrzeschik See my edited answer